# Laravel Layout Orientaton change

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

I am aware of CSS media queries such as

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    div.container {
        ...
    }
}
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    div.container {
        ...
    }
}
```

However I wish to make use of bootstrap fully to react to the screen orientation changes. I also know that the actual blade is not reactive.
The 2 layouts would be rendered statically as:

Portrait

```
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex min-vh-100 flex-column">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div id="dashboard"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row flex-fill fill d-flex red">
            <div class="col ">
                Content Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem..
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and landscape

```
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex min-vh-100 flex-column">
        <div class="row flex-fill fill d-flex">
            <div class="col-1">
                <div id="dashboard"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col ">
                Content Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem..
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am not sure how to combine these html and css. I do not want to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Resorted to pure HTML and CSS as being the cleanest method, using flexbox:

```
<header>header</header>
<div class="dd-bodyframe">
    <div class="dd-body">
        main body content
    </div>
    <div class="dd-body-pre">
        pre body content
    </div>
    <div class="dd-body-aft">
        after main
    </div>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

and the css

```
body,.dd-bodyframe {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.dd-body-pre {
    order: -1;
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    .dd-bodyframe {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex: 1;
    }
    .dd-body {
        flex: 1;
    }
    .dd-body-pre, .dd-body-aft {
        /* 12em is the width of the columns */
        flex: 0 0 12em;
    }
}
```